# php convert a string to csv file,

Tags: php, regex, string, csv

**Backgroud**
below is a single string that is contained in a file which is created by another program.

**actual string output**

```
site,monster,cat,name,   <br/>`site`='Lochness',`monster`='dinasour',`cat`='Feathered'Anchiornis<br/>`site`='Lochness',`monster`='dinasour',`cat`='Feathered'Pelecanimimus<br/>`site`='Lochness',`monster`='dinasour',`cat`='Feathered'Sinosauropteryx prima<br/>`site`='Lochness',`monster`='dinasour',`cat`='Feathered'Protarchaeopteryx robusta
```

I have split the string up below to make it easier to read but the actual string appears as above 
with no line breaks

**Easeier reading string output**
    site,monster,cat,name,
    
`site`='Lochness',`monster`='dinasour',`cat`='Feathered'Anchiornis
    
`site`='Lochness',`monster`='dinasour',`cat`='Feathered'Pelecanimimus
    
`site`='Lochness',`monster`='dinasour',`cat`='Feathered'Sinosauropteryx prima
    
`site`='Lochness',`monster`='dinasour',`cat`='Feathered'Protarchaeopteryx robusta

**Required output**
I would like to convert it to a csv file / string as follows for use by other scripts.

```
site, monster, cat, name
Lochness, dinasour, Feathered, Anchiornis
Lochness, dinasour, Feathered, Pelecanimimus
Lochness, dinasour, Feathered, Sinosauropteryx prima
Lochness, dinasour, Feathered, Protarchaeopteryx robusta
```

My pseudo code is as follows use preg_replace() and str_replace(), str_split() to remove the following strings
    1. replace 
 with \n (new line)
    2. remove anything between `and ' eg`site`=' as these are the same as the header row
    3. split last column into cat and name field

**Attempted code**
I have tried numerous ways to remove/replace the unwanted part of the strings etc but have been unsuccessful in removing all the strings required.
my regular expression experience is fine for simple individual characters but not much good for complex strings. The code below shows one of my attempts

```
    <?php

// replace carriage returns with new lines
$str = $re_html;

function br2nl($str) {
    $str = preg_replace("/(\r\n|\n|\r)/", "", $str);
    return preg_replace("=<br */?>=i", "\n", $str);
    }
br2nl($str);
echo $str; 
?>
```

Being a newbie to php any easily understood solutions greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does the string actually look like that with all those backticks and br tags and the last element not enclosed in quotation marks? If not, try and just put it all in a code block with no other formatting. And if it does, can you not change it? Because that's just a horrendous mess that you'll never be able to maintain adequately.

Comment: You are correct that is exactly how the string is.

Comment: a) You are correct that is exactly how the string is. How do I put it in a code block? b) I need  a csv format because this is the format used by other scripts downline. c) the file is generated from an existing mysql ajax php program which is quite complex, I tried but thought changing the output would be easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string is so complex that I'd be wary of using a regular expression for it, this does the trick:

```
<?php

$string = "site,monster,cat,name,<br/>`site`='Lochness',`monster`='dinasour',`cat`='Feathered'Anchiornis<br/>`site`='Lochness',`monster`='dinasour',`cat`='Feathered'Pelecanimimus<br/>`site`='Lochness',`monster`='dinasour',`cat`='Feathered'Sinosauropteryx prima<br/>`site`='Lochness',`monster`='dinasour',`cat`='Feathered'Protarchaeopteryx robusta";

$byLine = explode('<br/>', $string);
$keys = explode(',', substr(array_shift($byLine), 0, -1));

$csv = implode(', ', $keys) . "\n";

$lineCount = count($byLine);
for($i = 0; $i < $lineCount; $i++)
{
    $entry = explode(',', $byLine[$i]);
    $count = count($entry);
    for($j = 0; $j < $count; $j++)
    {
        $value = explode('`=\'', $entry[$j])[1];
        $lastApos = strrpos($value, '\'');
        if($lastApos === strlen($value) - 1)
        {
            $csv .= substr($value, 0, -1) . ', ';
        }
        else
        {
            $csv .= implode(', ', explode('\'', $value));
        }
    }
    if(($i + 1) < $lineCount)
    {
        $csv .= "\n";
    }
}

var_dump($csv);
```

Produces:

```
string 'site, monster, cat, name
Lochness, dinasour, Feathered, Anchiornis
Lochness, dinasour, Feathered, Pelecanimimus
Lochness, dinasour, Feathered, Sinosauropteryx prima
Lochness, dinasour, Feathered, Protarchaeopteryx robusta' (length=221)
```

**Edit**: And if for the sake of argument you did want to use a crazy regex for it, this is what you'd need:

```
<?php 

$string = "site,monster,cat,name,<br/>`site`='Lochness',`monster`='dinasour',`cat`='Feathered'Anchiornis<br/>`site`='Lochness',`monster`='dinasour',`cat`='Feathered'Pelecanimimus<br/>`site`='Lochness',`monster`='dinasour',`cat`='Feathered'Sinosauropteryx prima<br/>`site`='Lochness',`monster`='dinasour',`cat`='Feathered'Protarchaeopteryx robusta";

$regex = "#<br/>\`\w*\`=\'(\w*)',\`\w*\`=\'(\w*)',\`\w*\`=\'(\w*)'([\w\s]*)#";
$replace = "\n$1, $2, $3, $4";

$keyPos = strpos($string, ',<br/>');

$keys = str_replace(',', ', ', substr($string, 0, $keyPos));
$values = substr(preg_replace($regex, $replace, substr($string, $keyPos)), 2);

var_dump($keys . "\n" . $values);
```

Which also produces:

```
string 'site, monster, cat, name
Lochness, dinasour, Feathered, Anchiornis
Lochness, dinasour, Feathered, Pelecanimimus
Lochness, dinasour, Feathered, Sinosauropteryx prima
Lochness, dinasour, Feathered, Protarchaeopteryx robusta' (length=221)
```

Comment: Thanks I will give this a go and update you shortly, I know this is a complex string, but the legacy program is even more complex lol!

Comment: @GeorgeThompson I've added in a RegEx solution if you prefer

Comment: Hi @MrLore I ran the script and am getting the following error   Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/string2csv2.php on line 17 any ideas? I am currently trying to resolve the error. Thanks

Comment: @GeorgeThompson Is that on the first one? My regex one doesn't even have a line 17

Comment: Yes its on the first one I was updating when you posted the second solution, The second one works a treat I'd like to get the first script working as it will take a bit of time to get my head around that regular expression, Thanks.

Comment: I did slightly change the first solution when I posted the second, have you definitely got the current version of it?

Comment: @GeorgeThompson Perhaps there are still some new line characters in the text file that need to be removed with your first preg replace again?

Comment: @GeorgeThompson Then I'd start printing out the variables to make sure the file matches the output of the test string you gave

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
$str = preg_replace_callback("~(?>(?>',|(,?+\s*+<br/>))[^']++)?'|,~", 
    function ($m) { return (isset($m[1]))? "\n":', '; }, $str);
```